# Upgrading 2.1.4 from 2.1.6 manually using zip archive

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

I am currently developing locally using MAMP. I originally installed Magento 2.1.4 from a software archive (zip). I’d like to upgrade to 2.1.6. Can I just do a fresh install from the latest zip archive and use the 2.1.4 database? I can’t seem to find any documentation for this method with Magento 2 but I have seen it mentioned with Magento 1.

I assumed it would be fine as long as I merged the old media folder, the theme and the extensions into the new file structure. I’d like to know whether I’m doing this in an acceptable way and whether it could cause problems in the future.

I’d be grateful if someone knows the correct steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the upgrade this way. When you use database from 2.1.4 installation your instance will through an exception saying schema is out dated. In this case you can run setup upgrade. Now I'm assuming you will replace media , app/code and app/design folders only. 
**But**
The right way to do it is using composer as devdocs suggest. 
Go to your magento installation directory
And run

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 --no-update
```

This will update your composer. Jon
After this simply run

```
composer update
```

Later set up upgrade and you are done. This is the way to do it in production.